# How can I find out what so_type an existing unix socket has in macOS?

Tags: macos, lsof, unix-sockets, ss

In linux we can run `ss -x` or `lsof -U +E` and we can see what type unix socket has. But in macOS there is no `ss` or we can run `lsof -U` which only shows TYPE - unix, but I would like to know with some utility what exactly so_type a unix socket has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS appears to support the 'netstat' command.  Netstat has long been deprecated for linux due to the interface it used.  'ss' is a syntactically similar command for linux.

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten about `netstat`. I read its man and ran `netstat -f unix` and found my address and its type.